# Trying to find the cause of this crash

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm examining crashlytics. Followed the stack trace and have his error:

```
HTTPManager.swift line 313
specialized HTTPManager.(createAuthenticationParameters in _F8C28254BDE35F2F2E746C55EB4303F3)() -> [String : AnyObject]
```

with:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010017c690
```

Method is like so:

```
private func createAuthenticationParameters() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
    if User.sharedInstance.facebookID != nil {
        parameters["facebook_id"] = User.sharedInstance.facebookID!
    } else if User.sharedInstance.email != nil {
        parameters["email"] = User.sharedInstance.email!
    }
    parameters["auth_token"] = User.sharedInstance.authToken!

    return parameters // LINE 313
}
```

What could be causing it to crash? I'm only putting values in a dictionary. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you need to use "if let" instead of obj != nil

Comment: what is the line of code at line 313 in this file.

Comment: @Avaan edited my question.

Comment: @Atrash sorry my question had the wrong code. Edited it now. It crashes on the return line.

Comment: Could it be that it is trying to unwrap a nil optional on line 311 and then crashing? However the crash report says the crash happens on line 313...

Comment: Don't use `!`. Explicitly unwrapping optionals that may not be there will cause a crash and misuses one of the most powerful parts of swift. It may seem painful to write `if let` or `guard let` all over but you will see it pay off in leaps and bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try to rewrite your code like so:

```
private func createAuthenticationParameters() -> [String: Any] {
    var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
    if let facebookID = User.sharedInstance.facebookID {
        parameters["facebook_id"] = facebookID
    } else if let email = User.sharedInstance.email {
        parameters["email"] = email
    }

    if let token = User.sharedInstance.authToken {
        parameters["auth_token"] = token
    }

    return parameters // LINE 313
}
```